# Scope data not binding to {{ }}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind scope data to HTML using angular data binding {{ }} technique, but I'm getting POSTS as output, I tried referring articles in stack websites but couldn't figure out what went wrong, tried $scope.apply also but no luck! suggest me a fix!

```
(function () {
angular
    .module("BlogApp",[])
    .controller("BlogController", BlogController);

function BlogController($scope,$http){
    $scope.createPost=createPost;
    function init(){

        getAllPosts();
    }
    init();
    function getAllPosts(){
        $http
            .get("/api/blogpost")
            .success(function(posts){
                $scope.posts = "posts";
            });
    }
    function createPost(post){
        console.log(post);
        $http
            .post("/api/blogpost",post)
            .success(getAllPosts);
    }
}
})();
```

I have added ng-app in HTML tag

```
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">


    <h1>Blog</h1>

    <input ng-model="post.title" class="form-control" placeholder="title" />
    <textarea ng-model="post.body" class="form-control" placeholder="title"> </textarea>
    <button ng-click="createPost(post)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Post</button>

    {{posts}}

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of `$scope.posts = "posts";` It should be `$scope.posts = posts;`

Comment: Could you provide the solution as a self-answer to help future readers?

Comment: Nothing much ! I forget to add the doublequotes to call the post parameters. Aman pointed out me towards the bug. Thanks Aman